# JButton not responding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hi I'm fairly new at Java and right now I'm troubleshooting someone else's code because a button is not responding. When clicked on UI nothing happens.

I would really appreciate some help on this thanks.
(Adding some words because stackoverflow is telling me that It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.)

Here's the code:

```
private JButton printAddressButton;
String p_link = http://www.google.com/images/logo_google_suggest.gif;
String printer_keyword = "DYMO";


private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setSize(100, 35);
    printAddressButton.setText("Print Here");
    printAddressButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
    printAddressButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            printAddressButton_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(printAddressButton, null);
}

private void printAddressButton_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    print_address(p_link);
}

public void print_address(String link) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Servlet URL: " + link + ", Printer Keyword: " + printer_keyword);
        PrintService services[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("Number of printers: " + services.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(services[i].getName());
            PrintService myprinter = services[i];
            if (services[i].getName().indexOf(printer_keyword) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Found " + printer_keyword + " printer: " + services[i]);
                DocPrintJob print_job = myprinter.createPrintJob();
                URL url = new URL(link);
                DocFlavor flavor = "GET".equalsIgnoreCase(method) ?
                                    javax.print.DocFlavor.URL.PNG:
                                    javax.print.DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
                DocAttributeSet doc_attrs = new HashDocAttributeSet();
                doc_attrs.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
                SimpleDoc doc = "GET".equalsIgnoreCase(method) ?
                                new SimpleDoc(url, flavor, doc_attrs) :
                                new SimpleDoc(createHttpRequestWithPostMethod(url).getInputStream(), flavor, doc_attrs);
                PrintRequestAttributeSet print_attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                print_attrs.add(new Copies(1));
                print_attrs.add(new MediaPrintableArea(20, 30, 56, 84, 1000));
                print_job.print(doc, print_attrs);
                System.out.println("finished printing");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the console, if it print something when you click on it

Comment: Right before the `try` in the print_address method. put a print statement to show the method has been entered.  If it hasn't your problem lies elsewhere.  Note that if the process takes a long time, it will lock up the GUI since events on the EDT are processed sequentially,  I would also recommend using a layout manager rather than doing absolute positioning of components.

Comment: You are using *PNG DocFlavors, but your URL points to a GIF.  A GIF is not a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

After your line `for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {` insert `System.out.println("Looping " + i);` and you will see in the console that it actually runs, but it probably takes such a long time to finish, that it looks like it's not running.